# How to set an iPad back to factory settings where I have forgotton the restrictions passcode?

Tags: ipad

I am trying to help my uncle reset his iPad. He has not had it long and has forgotten the restrictions passcode (to manage restrictions in Settings). He is OK with putting it back to the factory settings. However, the restrictions code is required to do the reset. How do we bypass it and reset it?

*The restrictions passcode is required to set and enforce limits on age restrictions, categories and other parts of the iPad's interface in Settings.*

Comment: What do you mean "restrictions code"? I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: I think @Mary is referring to the passcode required to set Restrictions in Settings [Settings, General, Restrictions, Enable Restrictions] - *edit: added description to question.*

Comment: Are you trying to “Reset to Factory Settings” or “Erase all Content and Reset to Factory Settings”?

Answer (score 3):

Connect it to a computer, open iTunes and click "Restore" in the "Summary" tab for the device. Note that you will lose all data and settings on the iPad.

See: [iTunes: Restoring iOS software](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414)

Answer (score 0):

Put the iPad in [DFU Mode](http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/04/ipad-dfu-mode/) first. This will let you bypass any software problems, even if your device is bricked.